# Complete Metric Spaces and Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

$\textbf{Question}$:

Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in a complete metric space $(X, d)$ such that $$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} d(x_n, x_{n+1}) < +\infty. $$ Show that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges and this is no longer true if we assume that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} d^{2}(x_n, x_{n+1}) < +\infty.$

$\textbf{Solution}$:

I believe that I have shown the convergence in the case where $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} d(x_n, x_{n+1}) < +\infty$ by using the triangle inequality on $d(x_n, x_{n+m})$ for any $(n,m) \in \mathbb{N}^2.$ More explicitly, $$ (\forall n \in \mathbb{N})(\forall m \in \mathbb{N}) ~~~~ d(x_n, x_{n+m}) \leq \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{m - 1} d(x_{n + k}, x_{n+k+1}) \leq \sum\limits_{k = n}^{+\infty} d(x_{k}, x_{k+1}) \leq \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}} d(x_{k}, x_{k+1}) < +\infty. $$ Hence, $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy.

I am, however, having trouble providing a counterexample for the case where we only have $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} d^{2}(x_n, x_{n+1}) < +\infty.$ Ideally, I would like to generate some sequence in a complete metric space $(X, d)$ where  $$ (\forall n \in \mathbb{N}) ~~~~ d(x_n, x_{n+1}) = \frac{1}{n+1} $$ (note that I adopt the convention that $\mathbb{N} = \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, \dots \}$). This would then allow me to appeal to the fact that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{n + 1}$ diverges but $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{(n + 1)^2}$ converges. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Exactly right. Just push a little harder on your example.  E.g., if $x_n=1+\frac12 +\frac13 + \dots + \frac1n$ in $\mathbb R$ what is $d(x_n, x_{n+1}) $?

Comment: Shouldn't you show that $d(x_n,x_{n+m})<\varepsilon$?

Comment: For the first part, stop the inequality at $\sum_{k=n}^\infty$.  You lost all you had achieved when you went a step further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $\varepsilon>0$. Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty d(x_n,x_{n+1})$ concerges, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $\sum_{n=N}^\infty d(x_m,x_{n+1})<\varepsilon$. Then, if $m>n\geqslant N$,\begin{align}d(x_n,x_m)&\leqslant d(x_n,x_{n+1})+d(x_{n+1},x_{n+2})+\cdots+d(x_{m-1},x_m)\\&\leqslant\sum_{n=N}^\infty d(x_m,x_{n+1})\\&<\varepsilon.\end{align}So, $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence, and therefore it converges.

On the other hand, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sqrt[4]{n+1}-\sqrt[4]n\right)^2$ converges, but the sequence $\left(\sqrt[4]n\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ diverges.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This definitely works.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.